# Add job in Jenkins CLI

Tags: jenkins, command-line-interface

I have a pipeline job and a `jenkins.war`.

This is the command I run:

```
sudo java -jar /home/ubuntu/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 create-job test</home/ubuntu/jobs/test.xml
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
"ERROR: Unexpected exception occurred while performing create-job command.", 
    "com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: flow-definition", 
    "\tat com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:79)",
```

Comment: Check if your `test.xml` contains something that might let Jenkins try to load a class which isn't there. Also check that you've got a recent `jenkins-cli.jar`.

Comment: You should reconsider the need to run java / jenkins with superuser rights... If that's needed, then something is setup wrongly IMHO

Comment: 1) nohup sudo java -jar /home/ubuntu/jenkins.war  2)curl -o /home/ubuntu/jenkins-cli.jar -fsSL localhost:8080/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar   3)    sudo java -jar /home/ubuntu/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 create-job test</home/ubuntu/jobs/test.xml  4) job i create and export, but when i import job appears error

Comment: https://github.com/dedarh/Docker/blob/master/job.xml  my xml

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by an invalid job specification in `test.xml`.

If you want to play with the `create-job` CLI command, then best start with a job config XML of some existing job that you downloaded from the Jenkins GUI (`.../job/NAME/config.xml`). You can be sure that it holds a valid specification.

Answer (score 0):

you configuration xml is invalid...because if xml is valid should be like this
[click_here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1Drw.png)

to generate xml from other jobs you can use command

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -auth <user>:<passwd> get-job myfolder/myproject
```

to export it to xml you can type

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -auth <user>:<passwd> get-job myfolder/myproject > myproject.xml
```